# jquery performance - page lags on clearing .html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search form that does an ajax post to search for users in my database. The search can potentially yield thousands of results, and those are output into a place holder:

```
resultHtml = "<table class='table table-striped'>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<th style='width: 40%;'>Customer Name</th>" +
    "<th style='width: 40%;'>Office</th>" +
    "<th style='width: 15%;'></th>" +
    "</tr>";

$.each(data.searchResults, function(index, item) {
    resultHtml += "   <tr id='row_" + item.Id + "'>";
    resultHtml += "       <td style=\"width: 40%;\">" + item.FullName + "</td>";
    resultHtml += "       <td style=\"width: 40%;\">" + item.CompanyName + "</td>";
    resultHtml += "       <td style=\"width: 15%; padding-right: 10px; text-align: right;\">";
    resultHtml += "           <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn-link custUse\" name=\"custUse\" id=\"custUse\">Use</button>";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custId\" id=\"sr_custId\" value=\"" + item.Id + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custFirstName\" id=\"sr_custFirstName\" value=\"" + item.FirstName + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custLastName\" id=\"sr_custLastName\" value=\"" + item.LastName + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custCompanyId\" id=\"sr_custCompanyId\" value=\"" + item.CompanyId + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custCompanyName\" id=\"sr_custCompanyName\" value=\"" + item.CompanyName + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custCompanyAddress\" id=\"sr_custCompanyAddress\" value=\"" + item.CompanyAddress + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custCompanyCity\" id=\"sr_custCompanyCity\" value=\"" + item.CompanyCity + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custCompanyState\" id=\"sr_custCompanyState\" value=\"" + item.CompanyState + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custCompanyZip\" id=\"sr_custCompanyZip\" value=\"" + item.CompanyZip + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custEmail\" id=\"sr_custEmail\" value=\"" + item.Email + "\">";
    resultHtml += "           <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sr_custPhone\" id=\"sr_custPhone\" value=\"" + item.Phone + "\">";
    resultHtml += "       </td>";
    resultHtml += "   </tr>";
});
resultHtml += "</table>";

hideLoading();
$("#customerResults").html(resultHtml);
```

That performs pretty much as I expect it to. However, if the user clicks the "reset search" button, I get a VERY large lag on the page as it clears the search results:

```
$('#customerResults').html('');
```

That one line by itself can semi-lock the page (you can't click on anything until it finishes).

I'm curious on whether there's a faster way, a better way, to quickly clear those search results?

Comment: So, `$('#customerResults').empty();`?

Comment: I was also wondering about if I took all those hidden fields it's making for every row of the search, and instead made them 1 hidden field, where the value was a delimited string of all of the keys and values, and then ripped that apart when they chose that search result, if that might also speed it up? I'm just not sure how I'd rip apart the resultant string easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use .empty()

For better performance use

```
$('#customerResults').empty();
```

### Additional info

- [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)
- [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-empty-vs-html/33)